# Android Room Database throwing "CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on an android app where I have to Query all the columns and rows from the Table in room database which may have rows between 1 to 100000. At any point of time I need all the rows. App works fine most of the time but after few days, It crashes with the exception mentioned below:

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=1 (# cursors opened by this proc=1)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:138)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:219)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:268)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker$1.checkUpdatedTable(InvalidationTracker.java:358)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(InvalidationTracker.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

There doesn't seem to be any issue with open cursors because **Room** takes care of it itself. Also, number of open cursors is clearly mentioned in the exception as 1.

From the logs, it is quite clear that **CursorWindow has a size of 2 MB and allocation failed because Query Size exceeded**. But, **sometimes it fails even if the table has only few rows**.

I tried with annotation `@Transaction` but I am not sure about its success.

Is there any solution of this problem anywhere? Please Note that **I am NOT using SQLITE directly**. It is **ROOM**. Also, **I am not saving any Complex data in the table**.

Comment: What are you storing in your rows? Row size is what matters.

Comment: Do you have any potentially-large columns in your table, such as a `byte[]` for an image? Beyond that, you may simply have a too-fragmented heap. Make sure you are letting your app go in the background (so ART can compact the heap on Android 5.0-7.1 devices, and so your process can be terminated from time to time).

Comment: @CommonsWare    No..I am not saving any byte[ ] for any image in the table.

Comment: @laalto Table doesn't contain complex data. Yes, number of rows is something which will go on increasing if device remains offline.

Comment: Hello....Any solution?